# How to configure sonicwall to allow systems from internet to access dlink ip camera?

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I am trying to configure sonicwall to allow access for the ip camera from internet. The camera somehow sends out ARP packets which are being dropped at the firewall.

When used packetmonitor to see why they are being dropped, it is showing codes for NULL IP. When I disable the rule from the firewall, it shows packets dropped because of firewall rule.

Sonicwall firewall is: TZ 215
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help someone else.
The reason was: the gateway was not set in the IPCamera. that's why the camera was making the ARP requests to the public IP from where the connection was originated. The firewall was dropping the ARP connections. Once the IPcamera's gateway was set, it started working!